# Filter a Dataset with Multiple Conditions

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to filter a large amount of data from an access database. I am building a program to accomplish this, but am running into an issue for using multiple criteria in the filter. For instance, here is test code for selection using a given month and color:

```
If RadioButton1.Checked Then
    If RadioButton4.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[January] = 'True' AND [Red] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[January] = 'True' AND [Yellow] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[January] = 'True' AND [Blue] = 'True'"
    Else Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[January] = 'True'"
    End If
ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
    If RadioButton4.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[February] = 'True' AND [Red] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[February] = 'True' AND [Yellow] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[February] = 'True' AND [Blue] = 'True'"
    Else Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[February] = 'True'"
    End If
ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
    If RadioButton4.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[March] = 'True' AND [Red] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton5.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[March] = 'True' AND [Yellow] = 'True'"
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked Then
        Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[March] = 'True' AND [Blue] = 'True'"
    Else Me.BindingSource.Filter = "[March] = 'True'"
    End If
End If
```

Now this is a large amount of code for even three months and colors. There has to be a better way to do this, right? With as many fields in the table I need to sort it would take me years to do it this way.

Comment: If you have 12 bool columns for Months rather than one string column, I'd revisit the db design.  Same for a bunch of colors.

Comment: The reason for that is that items can have multiple months, multiple colors, etc.

Comment: That is just a different design flaw: you missed a 1:m relationship.  It doesnt take 12 columns to describe one attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not create the original database, considering the size of the thing it would be much more time consuming to fix it than to program around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split out the month buttons from the colour buttons, along the lines of:

```
Dim wc as string
'months
    if RadioButto1.Checked then wc = "January = true"
elseif radiobutton2.checked then wc = "February = true"
. . . . 

end if
'colours
If radiobutton4.checked then
wc &= " AND Red = true"
elseif radiobutton5.checked then
wc &= " AND Yellow = true"
. . . . .
end if


me.bindingsource.filter = wc
```

Comment: Ok, I tried using variables in the filter command but my syntax must have been wrong because it just dumped out on me, I'll match your syntax and see what happens.

Comment: This is working great, just had to add an addition If group for cases in which color but not month are selected. Once I finish up some functions I can expand the code to cover the complete database. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

For code this simple, you could use Switch statements:

```
Dim sMonth As String
Dim sColor As String

sMonth = Switch(RadioButton1.Checked, "[January]", RadioButton2.Checked, "[February]", RadioButton3.Checked, "[March]")
sColor = Switch(RadioButton4.Checked, "[Red]", RadioButton5.Checked, "[Yellow]", RadioButton6.Checked, "[Blue]")

Me.BindingSource.Filter = sMonth & " = 'True' AND " & sColor & " = 'True'"
```

This is still readable. You could also use a Select Case statement, the trick is to separate it into two parts.

Comment: VB.NET doesnt have a `Switch` function.  I think the MSAccess tag just means the OP uses access as the data repository.

Comment: Or the OP mis-tagged his question. The original code is valid VBA.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it ms-access since it is using an access database rather than sql or something else.